# iis apache web server

Tags: apache, iis-7, web

ok i got iis 7.0 installed on vista home premium was working on web matrix exploring

now it's taking up my port 80

i have installed xampp server and wanna run apache 2
 **how do i stop iis without uninstalling it?**

here is what i have tryed
 on microsoft web site it says in elevated commandline (run as admin) type iisreset /stop doesn't work

use gui = i don have that cuz i installed it through web matrix may be it comes when you install iis individually

Answer (score 0):

from the command line, try

```
c:\>net stop w3svc
```

Or, if that doesn't work, you could try running 'services.msc' and then manually disable/stop the "WWW Publishing Service"

Comment: just tryed ur way + c:\>net stop was

Comment: doesn't work says error 1060 the service doesn't exist as an installed service